# Counter Using Spring's JPA Repositories

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm pretty sure this is a common scenario - I have a table with a column that acts as a counter. I need to increment the value and need to know the incremented value.

I could do something like this with Spring's JPA repositories:

```
@Transactional
public getNextValue(){
    DataPO po = repository.find("someId");
    po.setCounter(po.getCounter+1);
    repository.save(po);
}
```

The downside of this it uses locking and is therefore slow.

I read about an approach using **last_insert_id** to do this efficiently but the examples that I found don't use repositories, they use **EntityManager** directly: [sample](https://theodoreyoung.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/jpa-counters-and-sequences/)

This is from the linked page:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE counter SET value = LAST_INSERT_ID(value + 1) WHERE name = :name");
query.setParameter("name", client.getName());
query.executeUpdate();

query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
long value = ((BigInteger) query.getSingleResult()).longValue();
value = value - 1;
```

Is there a way to do this with Spring's JPA repositories? I cannot find anything in the documentation: [Spring's JPA Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Is there any other efficient approach that I can follow with JPA repositories?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I thought it's clear when I wrote about locking. I should have been more precise on that. It's multi-threaded and the counter is no ID. I need to update the counter and get it back and this efficiently w/o introducing race conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Native Queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries/) from Spring Data JPA.

**In your case:**

```
public interface CounterRepository extends JpaRepository<Counter, Long>{

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE Counter SET value = LAST_INSERT_ID(value + 1) WHERE name = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    int updateCounterByName(String name);

    @Query(value = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", nativeQuery = true)
    int getLastInsertId();

    Counter findOneByName(String name);

}
```

Checkout the [Complete Project](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/SpringDataDemo) on my GitHub repository.